# Find certain rectangle SUM in matrix with negative integers (JAVA)

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array, sum, rectangles

I've to find a certain rectangle sumin matrix. I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467855/how-to-find-if-a-subarray-has-a-specific-sum-inside-a-2d-array-in-java)
But this doesn't seem to work with negative integers in matrix. How could i change the code so it would work with negative integers? I'm hopeless now.
Matrix is in the code

`output should be:
desired number @ (top,left) - (right,bottom)
12 @ (0,3) - (2,4)
12 @ (0,4) - (4,5)
12 @ (2,2) - (2,3)
12 @ (4,0) - (4,1)
my output: 
12 @ (0,4) - (1,5)
12 @ (2,2) - (3,3)
12 @ (3,0) - (4,2)
12 @ (4,0) - (5,4)`

Code i used:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] A = {
            {-13, 9 ,-16 , 14,   3},
            {11,  7 , -5 , 14,   9},
            {-2,  -5,  9 , -9 , -4},
            {11,  13,  3 ,  8 ,-16},
            {-1, -15,  1 , -4,   2},
            {3 ,  7,  -8 ,  0,  27},
    };
    int target = 12;

    for (int i = 1; i < A.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < A[i].length; j++){
            A[i][j] += A[i - 1][j];
            System.out.print(A[i][j] + " ");
        }System.out.println("");
     }

    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < A.length; i1++) {
        for (int i2 = i1 + 1; i2 < A.length; i2++) {
            int j1=0, j2=0, s=0;

            while(j2<A[i1].length) {
                while(s<target && j2<A[i1].length) {
                    s += A[i2][j2] - (i1 > 0 ? A[i1-1][j2] : 0);
                    j2++;
                    if (s==target)
                        System.out.println(String.format("Found between (%d,%d) and (%d,%d)", i1, j1, i2, j2-1));
                }
                while(s>=target) {
                    s -= A[i2][j1] - (i1 > 0 ? A[i1-1][j1] : 0);
                    j1++;
                    if (s==target)
                        System.out.println(String.format("Found between (%d,%d) and (%d,%d)", i1, j1, i2, j2));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What result are you getting? are you getting Exceptions

Comment: no exeptions at all. It's just when the matrix is filled with positive intergers only it works fine it finds the rectangles where the sum of the target number is. But when you add negative integers its acting all crazy and doesn't find proper rectangle. bu for me i dont find a reason why it should work with negative numbers

Comment: I suggest you step through your code with a debugger. You possibly have errors in your loops from using the while loops eg.  while (s>= target). You'll probably get an index out of bounds exception

Comment: it doesnt throw anything. There is no problem with exceptions or sytax or anything like that. It just return false rectangles